# Vue CLI 3 - Error upgrading TailwindCss 1.9 to TailwindCss 2.0

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 vite-app project installed with Tailwindcss 1.9. I wanted to upgrade TailwindCss to version 2.0 but got the following error.

[image: error when trying to run server]

And this is my postcss.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after following the official documentation of TailwindCss I managed to upgrade to version 2.0.

Here's the official guide for integrating TailwindCss with Vue3 and Vite:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite

I assume there were some issues with the packages which got fixed meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in devDependencies in package.json and run: `npm install`

"postcss": "^7.0.35",

"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.1"

Make sure you have the latest version of Node

Official Doc
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build